# How to do a COUNTIFS in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to add a column to a pandas dataframe that replicates an excel COUNTIFS formula to count the number of rows that meet multiple criteria?
I currently have a basic 2 column dataframe with columns HOUR and SYMBOL. I want a 3rd column that runs the length of the dataframe and counts the number of times a HOUR + SYMBOL pair appear. I have added a picture of the dataframe so far and here I would be expecting another column with values
1
1
2
2
1

as '08' & 'AD NA' are the only pair to appear twice.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `groupby` and `transform`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(['HOUR','SYMBOL'])['HOUR'].transform('count')
```